# How do I use pattern and matcher to split a large string up into specific substrings in Java?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, design-patterns, matcher

I've never done this before, but basically I'm trying to break a large string up into substrings (based on a regular expression) and then make use of those substrings one at a time. Can anyone show me the easiest way to do this? I just don't quite know how to use the methods of pattern and matcher.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us one of those Strings please and someone will show you a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.String.split()` takes a regular expression and will split the string, returning a `String[]` containing the substrings:

```
String s = "a:very:big:string";
String[] parts = s.split(":");

for (String part: parts)
{
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

You don't need to use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to achieve this.

Comment: Well then how can I split up 

{(("q1", "1"), ("q2", "^", "R")), (("q2", "^"), ("q3", "1", "R"))}

into 2 pairs?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? What are the expected substrings?

Answer (score 1):

Basic info about pattern matching in Java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/